# Choose the Target SDK in Android Studio

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio

I need to see which SDKs I can choose, but when I go to the module settings (Android Studio (Preview) 0.5.8) I see only this
[image]

and I can't find this settings, where I can choose the Target SDK
[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the *targetSdkVersion* field of the *build.gradle* file.

This is an example:

```
defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 10
            targetSdkVersion 19
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0.0"
        }
```

Hope it helped, Mattia

Comment: Is not enought, becouse it's a third part sdk, that have api level 16, it works with eclipse, I see the different name (like when you see for the same api level, the google and android version)

Comment: You can only choose the _targetSdkVersion_ for the sources _you_ have. If it's an external jar you cannot choose the _targetSdkVersion_.

Comment: But in the other screen you can choose, just I don't find where is it that screen

Comment: That screen is just for project that does not support Gradle, for example the ones imported from Eclipse.